# Jquery receive parameter from cookie

Tags: php, jquery, html, cookies

I'm creating a menu that is nested within

```
<a href="#">
<div class="container"> </div>
<div class="title"> </div>
<div class="Chapter"> </div>
</a>
```

my PHP `foreachloop :` tells me how many of these container elements I have could be 10 or 20.

what i'm trying to do is use Jquery to tell me what the child number of the menu item I clicked on. currently i'm using

```
var count2 = $(this).parent().index();
```

Then i'm saving the parameter into a cookie, with `createCookie("menu",count2);`

*the cookie is setting correctly* and now contains a string say "10".

my question is: which jquery function can I use to receive the parameter of the child
number of the menu items and add a class to that menu item.

something along the lines of

```
if (readCookie("menu") != null) {

   $("a .container:nth-child(readCookie("menu")").removeClass("").addClass("active");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `eq(x)` returns the x-th result of your jquery selector.

```
$("a .container:eq(" + readCookie("menu") + ")").addClass("active");
```

Comment: You're welcome. Would be nice if you'd mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what plugin you're using to read/write cookies, but the following code works with this plugin...

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
var menu = $.cookie("menu");
if (menu) {
   $("a .container:nth-child(" + menu +")").addClass("active");
}
```

if `readCookie` in your example is correct then you want this...

```
var menu = readCookie("menu");
if (menu) {
   $("a .container:nth-child(" + menu +")").removeClass("").addClass("active");
}
```

I removed `removeClass("")` as that wasn't doing anything.